# In Rails, how and where to define a new method that slightly changes an existing Rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to define a version of Rails' `parameterize` that doesn't downcase the resulting string.

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/transliterate.rb, line 80
def parameterize(string, sep = '-')
  # replace accented chars with their ascii equivalents
  parameterized_string = transliterate(string)
  # Turn unwanted chars into the separator
  parameterized_string.gsub!(/[^a-z0-9\-_]+/, sep)
  unless sep.nil? || sep.empty?
    re_sep = Regexp.escape(sep)
    # No more than one of the separator in a row.
    parameterized_string.gsub!(/#{re_sep}{2,}/, sep)
    # Remove leading/trailing separator.
    parameterized_string.gsub!(/^#{re_sep}|#{re_sep}$/, '')
  end
  parameterized_string.downcase
end
```

I'd figured I would do this:

```
# /lib/inflector.rb
module Inflector
  module ParameterizeCs
    # Parameterize a string without making it lowercase
    # by editing Rails' parameterize
    def parameterize_cs(string, sep = '-')
        ....
    end
  end
end

# Actually monkey-patch Inflector
Inflector.include Inflector::ParameterizeCs
```

But I'm getting this error: `undefined method parameterize_cs`

Any ideas ?

Comment: Aren't you missing **end** for your **module ParameterizeCs**?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, like adding a class so you can call **parameterize_cs** method:

```
# /lib/inflector.rb
module Inflector
  class ParameterizeCs
    # Parameterize a string without making it lowercase
    # by editing Rails' parameterize
    def parameterize_cs(string, sep = '-')
        ....
    end
  end
end

# Actually monkey-patch Inflector
Inflector.include Inflector::ParameterizeCs
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first make sure that you have configured your config/application.rb file to load the files in /lib folder:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

This will automatically load your new file. However, from how you've set up, it would not go into `ActiveSupport::Inflector` but rather to the plain `Inflector` module that you've defined.

If you wanted to define that method in ActiveSupport::Inflector, you would have to specify the full path, after which you should be able to simply call that method. By the way, if you only have that single method, `module ParameterizeCs` seems unnecessary to me so I skipped it here.

```
module ActiveSupport
    module Inflector
        # Parameterize a string without making it lowercase
        # by editing Rails' parameterize
        def parameterize_cs(string, sep = '-')
            ....
        end
    end
end
```

Edit:

Please post the code where you try to `include` the module and call `parameterize_cs`. Otherwise it's difficult to pinpoint what could be wrong. But I'll put some more info based on my guess.

If you have loaded the file, then the method is already there. There's no need to `include` it again like that. You can check it by calling  `ActiveSupport::Inflector.instance_methods`, which will list all instance methods in `ActiveSupport::Inflector`. You should be able to see `:parameterize_cs` there.

Another thing to check is if you are trying to call `parameterize_cs` from the module itself, like `ActiveSupport::Inflector.parameterize_cs`. The method is defined as an instance method, so it can be only called from an instance of the class to which you've called `include ActiveSupport::Inflector`. The following code includes ActiveSupport::Inflector module to String (to make sure that `parameterize_cs` is loaded into String), then calls `parameterize_cs` from an instance of String.

```
String.include ActiveSupport::Inflector
s = "foobar"
s.parameterize_cs("bar")
```

If you wanted to call `parameterize_cs` directly from the module like `ActiveSupport::Inflector.parameterize_cs`, then declare the method as a class method (i.e. `def self.parameterize_cs`).

Comment: I did that, seems the file in /lib loads, but the function is still unavailable. What this line should be: `ActiveSupport.include ActiveSupport::Inflector`. This is the error I'm getting: `NoMethodError (undefined method parameterize_cs for #<User:0x007fb1102b95a8>):
  app/models/user.rb:56:in normalize_friendly_id
  config/initializers/friendly_id_finder.rb:10:in set_slug
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:27:in update_resource`

Comment: I've edited my answer. If it's still not working. please post more of your code .

Comment: That might work, but until then I have a different issue that might simplify my situation. Seems like on newer versions of rails this is possible: `"John Smith".parameterize(preserve_case: true) # => "John-Smith"` (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html), but when I try it on rails console on rails 4.2.0 I get this error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String`. Any ideas ? I will also review and try out your proposed solution as an exercise

Comment: `preserve_case` seems to be only available for Rails 5, which is still in its beta. Besides, that error is raised because you're calling that method on Hash instead of String. I think you're calling it on User object itself, instead of User.name or something like that.